# How i can work with extension attributes using collection?

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection, extension-attributes

Hello i have to add extension attributes to `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface`

So i added this one to `extension_attrributes.xml`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
        <attribute code="custom_attribute" type="int"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

And to `di.xml` added:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="extensionActions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="read" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="customAttributeReader" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Custom\Model\Product\CustomAttribute\ReadHandler</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="create" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="customAttributeCreator" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Custom\Model\Product\CustomAttribute\SaveHandler</item>

                    </item>
                    <item name="update" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="customAttributeSaver" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Custom\Model\Product\CustomAttribute\SaveHandler</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

So it`s work fine. When i get product entity using `ProductRepository` or `load()` function in Product model, all my extension attributes loads successful. **But i have some issue when i work with Collection:**

When i do something like:

```
$productCollection->addFieldToFilter('custom_attribute', 2);
```

My code don't wok and it's expected because my model not contains this attribute.

**So i have a question. How i can filter by my extension attribute using collection ?**

Also if i do:

```
$productCollection->getFirstItem()->getExtensionAttributes()
```

I get empty array.

So i need your help. I'll be very grateful!!!

Answer (score 0):

I added extension attributes with repository plugin. And works fine. But only with repository, so I'm also looking for solution.